# How can I determine if two vertices on a polygon are consecutive?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons

Suppose I have a set of points that construct a convex polygon in the Cartesian plane with the points as its vertices. I randomly choose two vertices and want to know if they are consecutive vertices on the polygon. Does anyone know of an algorithm that would do this, as in you would input the array of points and the two vertices as parameters and it would return a boolean?

It's given that the polygon exists and is unique.

Answer (score 12):

As the polygon is convex, it is simple! Two vertices are consecutive if all other vertices are located on the same side of the line that goes through these two points. This means that the cross product of the vector feom one of the pionts to the other one with the vector from the first point to any other one in the polygon have the same sign (all negative or all positive). For example, if those two points are called $P_1$ and $P_2$, you should compute all cross product of $\langle P_1, P_2\rangle$ with $\langle P_1, P_i\rangle$ ($P_i$ here means all other vertices).

Also, as discussed in the comment, we have some *degenerate cases*. The degenerate case is a common phenomenon in computational geometry, that is mostly handled separately. Here, the degenerate case is three points are located on a line.

Comment: Almost.  A polygonal convex hull can have multiple points on one of its segments.  (Easiest example: the set $\{1,2\} \times \{1,2,3\}$.)  However, adding a "check that there are no points on this edge in the segment between the two given points" is as easy to do as what you have described (using two half-spaces bounded by perpendiculars to the containing edge).

Comment: @EricTowers: Those points don't form the vertices of a convex polygon.

Comment: @user2357112 they sure do. Think of a rectangle with vertices added in the middle of the edges. It still looks like a rectangle so it's still convex.

Comment: As two different erics said this wont work when the cross product in this example is 0, which would mean it lies on the same line. Luckily this can be accounted for by finding the distance between the points on the same line using pythagoras theorem. But you must be careful and take into account direction as the two closest points are not necessarily the two either side. You can test for direction if we think about the line as a vector and the two points either side are the closest points for the same vector, and the opposite vector.

Comment: @user2357112 : All six vertices are on the perimeter of a rectangle.  Every pair of points in the union of the interior and the boundary bound a line segment contained in the union of the interior and the boundary.  It is therefore a polygon that is convex.

Comment: @EricTowers: The question specifically requires that the points be the **vertices** of the resulting polygon. Even if you can form a convex polygon from that set of points, the resulting polygon is a rectangle, with only four vertices.

Comment: @user2357112 : Why do you believe "vertex" excludes that is is the vertex of a straight angle?

Comment: @EricTowers: The vertices of a polygon are a geometric property of the polygon itself. The polygon you get from {1, 2} x {1, 2, 3} is the same polygon you get from {1, 2} x {1, 3}, and has the same set of vertices.

Comment: @user2357112 : The six points form a convex polygon with six vertices.  Two of which are vertices of straight angles.  You have reversed the OP's order of construction.  The points exist first; they are not extracted from the polygon.

Comment: @EricTowers: The points come first, but you cannot simply trace line segments through 6 points and declare that the 6 points are vertices without checking that they match the definition of "vertex", just like you cannot simply declare that the figure you get is convex, or a polygon. Even if you trace line segments through 6 points, if you get a rectangle, the points weren't all vertices of the rectangle you got.

Comment: @user2357112 : You seem to be confused.  A vertex of a straight angle is a real thing.  It is necessary.  Otherwise, many claims about the angles of two intersecting lines are impossible to state.  In other words: since there are angles of pi radians (and there is not some unexpected gap in the set of possible angles) there are vertices of straight angles.  Consequently vertices of straight angles are vertices.

Comment: @user2357112 : By the way "straight angle" is standard terminology and has been (with obvious linguistic variation) since Euclid.  For a current usage, see bullet points 5 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Individual_angles .

Comment: @EricTowers: I am not challenging the use of the term "straight angle". However, if you consider the "vertex" of a straight angle to be a vertex of a polygon, then every point on the polygon is a vertex, as every point on the polygon lies on some straight or non-straight angle.

Comment: @user2357112 : Again, you are reversing OP's construction.  OP has a set of points, all of which are declared vertices, even the ones which land on segments bounded by other vertices.  You seem to want to start with a polygon and extract the set of vertices from the extreme points of that object.  But that is not the construction you are given.

Answer (score 5):

Given that the polygon is convex, its centroid $C$ is in its interior. Test the gradients of the lines $CV$ for each vertex $V$. This gives a linear time test.

Comment: What do you mean, "test the gradients"? Do you mean that all the other gradients should be outside of the range defined by the gradients calculated with the two input vertices?

Comment: It's a bit more subtle than than, because of wrap-around between $\pm \infty$ and because that means there are two ranges. But essentially, yes.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to OmG's answer (which is great) would be to sort your points into an ordered array where you can find any points neighbors by looking at the points on either side. This method would be very good if you need to work with the same polygon for many calculations as most work is done upfront but afterwards the cost of determining if two points are neighbors is very small.

So how do we sort the array?

Let's say we have an array of our unsorted points where each point contains its x and y coordinates.

```
var points = [{x:1, y:0}, {x:6, y:8}, {x:-10, y:12} ...etc]
```

First we want to find the left-most and right-most points i.e highest and lowest x-values.
A function for this would look like the following:

```
//input the array of unsorted points
//also assuming a valid non-empty array
function getLeftMostPoint(points){
    //the point with the lowest x value.
    var leftMostPoint = points[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++){
        if(points[i].x < leftMostPoint.x){
            leftMostPoint = points[i];
        }
    }
    return leftMostPoint;
}
```

The rightmost point would be near-identical but the less-than would be swapped for a greater-than.

Next up we imagine we draw a line from our left-most point to our right-most point. Then we group all remaining points into two categories; those below the line and those above it.

```
//assuming we have left and rightmost points from above
//we are looping over the points (not shown here) and passing each one 
//as the current point in this function
//this will return a number. 
//If positive it means the current point is "above" the line
//negative means below the line and 0 means on the line.
function overOrUnder(leftMostPoint, rightMostPoint, currentPoint){
    return (currentPoint.x - leftMostPoint.x) * (rightMostPoint.y- leftMostPoint.y) - (currentPoint.y - leftMostPoint.y) * (rightMostPoint.x- leftMostPoint.x);
}
```

Now assuming we have stored all the points under/over into their own arrays we have all the info needed to build our sorted array or points.

1. We choose our starting point as the leftmostpoint
2. Then we add all values in the over array in x-ascending(smallest first) order.
3. Add the rightmostpoint
4. Add the values in the under array in x-descending order(biggest first)

The  result is an array where each point connects to the next point in the array and the final point connects back to the first. Note that this method gives a non-intersecting polygon as its result regardless of if the input is convex or concave. The output will only be guaranteed convex if the input is guaranteed convex.

See below for more complete code

```
//Input: array of unsorted polygon points
//Output: NEW array of sorted polygon points
function sortPoints(points){
    var sortedPoints = [];

    //Get the leftmost and rightmost points
    var leftMost = getLeftMostPoint(points);
    var rightMost = getRigthMostPoint(points);

    //array to hold the points that are over/under or middle(on the line)
    var over = [];
    var under = [];
    var middle = [];

    //loop the points and put them in the appropriate array depending on where they sit relative to the line
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
        //dont want/need to sort the left and right points
        if(points[i] != leftMost && points[i] != rightMost){
            var side = overOrUnder(leftMost, rightMost, points[i]);
            if(side < 0){
                under.push(points[i]);
            }else if(side > 0){
                over.push(points[i]);
            }else{
                middle.push(points[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    //There's an edge case with convex polygons where we don't know whether 
    //points on the line, i.e in the middle array, should be assigned to the over or 
    //under. The answer is we put them in the array which is empty
    if(middle.length > 0){
        if(over.length == 0){
            over = middle;
        }else{
            under = middle;
        }
    } 

    //as explained above we sort one descending and the other ascending.
    over.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.x - b.x;
    });

    over.sort(function(a, b){
        return b.x - a.x;
    });

    //now build up the array like explained above
    sortedPoints.push(leftMost);
    sortedPoints = sortedPoints.concat(under);
    sortedPoints.push(rightMost);
    sortedPoints = sortedPoints.concat(over);

    return sortedPoints;
}

function getLeftMostPoint(points){
    //the point with the lowest x value.
    var leftMostPoint = points[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++){
        if((points[i].x < leftMostPoint.x) || (points[i].x == leftMostPoint.x && points[i].y > leftMostPoint.y)){
            leftMostPoint = points[i];
        }
    }
    return leftMostPoint;
}

function getRightMostPoint(points){
    //the point with the lowest x value.
    var rightMostPoint = points[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++){
        if((points[i].x > rightMostPoint.x) || (points[i].x == rightMostPoint.x && points[i].y > rightMostPoint.y)){
            rightMostPoint = points[i];
        }
    }
    return rightMostPoint ;
}

function overOrUnder(leftMostPoint, rightMostPoint, currentPoint){
    return (currentPoint.x - leftMostPoint.x) * (rightMostPoint.y- leftMostPoint.y) - (currentPoint.y - leftMostPoint.y) * (rightMostPoint.x- leftMostPoint.x);
}
```

And there we have it! and now to check if points are next to each other is easy something like:

```
//given sorted array is available 
//this would return a boolean indicating whetehr point 1 and point 2 are next to each other
function(p1, p2) {
    var neighbours = false;
    var p1Index = sortedPoints.indexOf(p1);
    var p2Index = sortedPoints.indexOf(p2);

    //one index apart next to each other
    //or the edge cases where the points are at the start and ends of the array
    if (Math.abs(p1Index - p2Index) == 1) {
        neighbours = true;
    } else if (p1Index == 0 && p2Index == sortedPoints.length - 1) {
        neighbours = true;
    } else if (p1Index == sortedPoints.length - 1 && p2Index == 0) {
        neighbours = true;
    }
    return neighbours;
}
```